# Print sudoku box numbers

Tags: c, sudoku

I have written a function to display each sudoku box. However I wasn't able to find exactly the number of each box.
Here is the code:

```
void Print_Box(void)
{
  size_t i = 0U, j = 0U, k = 0U, m = 0U;
  size_t col = 0 , row = 0, G_SIZE = 9, BOX_SIZE = 3;

  for (; i < G_SIZE; i+=3)
  {
    row = (i/3)*3;
    printf("Box number %zd\n",row+1);
    for (j = 0; j < G_SIZE; j+=3)
    {
      col = (j/3)*3;
      for (k = 0; k < BOX_SIZE; k++)
      {
        for (m = 0; m < BOX_SIZE; m++)
        {
          printf("[%d] ",Grid[row+k][col+m]);
        }
        putchar('\t');
      }
      puts("");
    }
    puts("");
  }
  return;
}
```

And the grid:

```
int Grid[9][9]  =
{
  {1,0,5,0,2,0,0,0,2},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};
```

And here is the output:

```
Box number 1
[1] [0] [5]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     
[0] [2] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     
[0] [0] [2]     [0] [0] [0]     [2] [0] [0]     

Box number 4
[0] [0] [0]     [0] [8] [0]     [0] [0] [8]     
[0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     
[0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     

Box number 7
[0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     
[0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     
[0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]     [0] [0] [0]
```

The goal to display each box's number before printing the box, but I can't figure out a way. Any hints?

Comment: Can't you just do something like `printf("Box number %zd     Box number %zd     Box number %zd\n", row+1, row+2, row+3);`?

Comment: The box number can just be computed, using the (row,col) Take paper and pencil and do the math. (hint: make it a function)

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
for (j = 0; j < G_SIZE; j+=3)
```

to inside of

```
for (k = 0; k < BOX_SIZE; k++)
```

like this

```
int main()
{
        size_t i = 0U, j = 0U, k = 0U, m = 0U;
        size_t col = 0, row = 0, G_SIZE = 9, BOX_SIZE = 3;

        for (; i < G_SIZE; i += 3)
        {
            row = i;
            printf("Box number %zd\n", row + 1);
                for (k = 0; k < BOX_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < G_SIZE; j += 3)
                    {
                        col = j;
                    for (m = 0; m < BOX_SIZE; m++)
                    {
                        printf("[%d] ", Grid[row + k][col + m]);
                    }
                    putchar('\t');
                }
                puts("");
            }
            puts("");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

1. you need to count(+=3) 'col(j)' inside of count 'row(k)'
2. since you add '3' to i and j, you dont need to row = (i/3) * 3;, just row = i; is okay.